# Can you control which devices a push notification is sent to?

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

## Background

I've created and packaged (in a managed package) a Connected App that's configured to use Apple's push notification service (APNS). When installed into a client sandbox, and when I've logged into that org on a mobile device, code in the package can trigger a push notification to the device and it works correctly.

If I sign into that same org from a second mobile device however, that device never receieves the push notification, nor a third if I do that.

## Related Information

The in-built testing page on the Connected App screen lets you specify a specific device token to use to send the test notification too, but the methods provided for generating notifications via Apex only accept a list of user IDs, nothing device specific.

## The Question

Is there a way to send the push notification to all devices the user has authenticated with, or failing that, a way to send to the latest device *without* them having to log out of previously used devices?